# apache php javascript - Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/bla

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I hope some bright spark can help me here. I have a site I am building, on an apache web server (Raspberry Pi 2). I am coding the site in php.

`Index.php` has a div that is refreshed using a simple jQuery script I wrote.

`Index.php` includes /include/start/times.php

`times.php` includes /functions/time_func.php that calls a function to display live times in the index.php div.

The jQuery refreshes every 10 seconds.

When I first load the page, the div displays correctly.
When the jQuery runs 10 seconds later, the div is filled with the error in the title. I also get this error below:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'functions/times.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

I have looked at server permissions, and everything else I can think of. I'm hoping someone can help me this is causing me so much frustration now.

Interestingly, if I dump all the relevant files in my website root, and modify the inclusion paths, it all works fine :-/

Here are some file contents:

index.php:

```
<html>
<head lang="en">  
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>  
function updateLeft() {
var url = "include/start/times.php";
jQuery("#left").load(url);
}
setInterval("updateLeft()", 5000);
</script>
</head>
<body style="overflow-y: hidden;">
<?php
    include 'include/start/times.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

times.php:

```
<div id="left">
    <p class="no-margin text-shadow">Times: <br><br><span class="text-bold" id="pressure">
    <?php 
        include 'functions/time_func.php';
        times();
    ?>
    </span></p>
</div>
```

time_func.php:

```
<?php

    // Define the cURL function
    function curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20160904 Firefox/4");
        $page = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $page;
    }    

    function times(){
        $x_data = curl("http://mysite.james.com/test_sceh.html");
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($x_data);
        $sec1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0);
        $time1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(4);
        $sec2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(6);
        $time2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(10);
        $sec3 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(12);
        $time3 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(16);
        $xtime = $sec1->nodeValue . ' - ' . $time1->nodeValue . '<br>' . $sec2->nodeValue . ' - ' . $time2->nodeValue . '<br>' . $sec3->nodeValue . ' - ' . $time3->nodeValue . '<br>';
        print_r($xtime);         
    }
?>
```

Comment: From the error, it looks like you're trying to include a file that isn't there

Comment: Hi Marc, It does indeed yes, however the file is there, and executes when the page is first loaded. When jQuery subsequently tries to refresh the div, it then acts like it isn't there...

Comment: can you post Index.php, times.php and time_func.php contents?

Comment: Hi there, Done...

Comment: Initially copied an old version, refresh to see the live version. Just a few changed variable and file names...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the paths don't get resolved the same way.

When you load the page for the first time, it all starts from `index.php`
I guess 'functions' is at the same level as `include`

When your include paths are relative, they are relative to the ancestor.
So, relative to `index.php` when you load the page, but relative to `times.php` when you do your ajax request.

Because `functions` is not a subfolder of `include/start`, it fails to find the `time_func.php`

For this kind of scenario, where the same files are included from different parent folders, you should use an absolute path.

Something like:

`<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/start/times.php'; ?>`

and

`<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/functions/time_func.php'; ?>`

Or course, don't change the relative path you use in `var url`, it needs to remain relative to the root of the hostname.

Comment: Of course it is... I had looked at pretty much everything but this, and I feel stupid. 
Thanks very much for your input, that has sorted it out.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory